# Select all elements inside a div but not a particular one

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I select all elements inside `.content` but not `.bts`? Here is my code. I'm using the `not()` function to exclude `.bts` but it's not working. What should be done?

```js
$('.content').not('.bts').click(function() {
  alert("hit");
});
```

```css
.content {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

p {}

.bts {
  background: blue;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
  <p>test</p>
  <div class="bts">bts</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `$('.content *:not(.bts)')`

`.content *` means that it will take all elements on `.content`, adding `not(.bts)` removes all elements with the `bts` `class` from the rule.

**Demo**

```js
$('.content *:not(.bts)').click(function() {
  console.log("hit");
});
```

```css
.content {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

p {}

.bts {
  background: blue;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
  <p>test</p>
  <div class="bts">bts</div>
</div>
```

Comment: what does the * before :not mean ?

Comment: * means it selects all elements in `.content`

Comment: This does not register clicks on the `.content` itself.

Comment: @CertainPerformance I don't see anywhere in the question that it is a requirement. But i'll fix it. Btw your code does not trigger on `.content` itself either.

Answer (score 3):

The `.content` is not a `.bts`, so `.not` won't do anything - rather, pass another selector to the click handler, to avoid triggering the handler when the `.bts` is clicked:

```js
$('.content').on('click', ':not(.bts)', () => {
  console.log("hit");
});
```

```css
.content {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

p {}

.bts {
  background: blue;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
  <p>test</p>
  <div class="bts">bts</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can achieve it in Vanilla JS

```js
let elements = document.querySelectorAll(".content >:not(.bts)");
elements.forEach(ele => {
  ele.addEventListener("click", function() {
    alert("hit")
  })

})
```

```css
.content {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

p {}

.bts {
  background: blue;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
  <p>test</p>
  <div class="bts">bts</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since this answer hasn't been posted and is the simplest way to solve OP's issue according to his code, I'll do it : you just forgot to select `.content` children, you can do it with [`.children()`](https://api.jquery.com/children/#children-selector) function right after your `.content` selector like so :

```js
$('.content').children().not('.bts').click(function() {
  alert("hit");
});
```

```css
.content {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

p {}

.bts {
  background: blue;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
  <p>test</p>
  <div class="bts">bts</div>
</div>
```